# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have 2 entities, namely **Product** and **Category**,

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }  
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**Product Controller**

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private DemoContext db = new DemoContext();

        // GET: Products
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.Category);
            return View(products.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Products/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(product);
        }
    }
```

I try to access the CategoryName Property from Category Entity in the Product Details View as this

```
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
<label>@Model.Category.CategoryName</label>
<li>@Model.Price.ToString("##,###")</li>
```

But I got error **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

@Model.Category.CategoryName

Comment: Looks like the `Category` property has not been set. Could be the underlying entity framework you are using. You do use `Include` so I expect the problem to be in the entity framework mappings itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load `Category` navigation property as part of the query that you use to load a `Product`, you should change your query to this one:

```
Product product = db.Products.Include(p=>p.Category).FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ProductId ==id);
```

This is called eager loading and you can read more about it in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager)

Comment: Many thanks octavioccl, Gracefully appreciated to contributions

Comment: you're welcome @user2985240 ;)